# Hello I need a regex that does a conditional check (if there is a digit, i need to check if there is a at least one space and at least one character)

Tags: regex

Hello I need a regex that does a conditional check (if there is a digit, i need to check if there is a at least one space and at least one character).

I am very bad with regex lookaheads :(

example:
r ==> pass

test == > pass

5th ave ==> pass

4 ==> fail
test 5 test => pass

only if there is a number i want to fail if there is no space and another character in the string..

thank you,

-mark

Comment: Play around with https://regex101.com/
This will give you an intuition about how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this:

`/(([a-zA-Z]+)|(\d(?=[ a-zA-z])))/`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wW6pH7/1)